# If Printer Dialog Cancelled, Then Don't Print?

Tags: c#, printing, printdialog

If I run this code, and press cancel on the PrintDialog, it still prints.  How can I tell if the use pressed cancel?

```
PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();

dialog.ShowDialog();
document.PrinterSettings = p.PrinterSettings;
document.Print();
```

Addendum

```
WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();
w.ShowPrintDialog(); //.ShowPrintDialog returns a void, how can I deal with this?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the result of the ShowDialog method:

```
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
   //Print
}
```

Comment: What can I do with WebBrowser.ShowPrintDialog? It returns a void and not a DialogResult.

Answer (score 3):

ShowDialog returns a dialog result enumeration. It will either be OK, or Cancel.

```
PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();

if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
{
    document.PrinterSettings = p.PrinterSettings;
    document.Print();
}
```

Comment: Is there anything I can do with WebBrowser.ShowPrintDialog?It returns a void and not a DialogResult.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't thing there is a way to handle this. What would you like to do with the result? i.e. if the dialog was cancelled, what code would execute?

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are correct for [`System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog(v=vs.110).aspx). However, if you're not building a `Forms` application, the `PrintDialog` you will use is [`System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog(v=vs.110).aspx). Here, `ShowDialog` returns a `bool?`:

```
var dialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    // Print...
}
```